# how to get number of elements in an array in mongo db. I am using go lang ie mgo driver?

Tags: mongodb, go, bson, mgo

I have the following code but I am stuck in getting the the counts of likes as I get `nil` result.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    uri := "mongodb://root:tempyml@localhost:27017"

    sess, err := mgo.Dial(uri)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Can't connect to mongo, go error %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer sess.Close()

    sess.SetSafe(&mgo.Safe{})
    collection := sess.DB("visibl_dev").C("user_videos")

    pipe := collection.Pipe([]bson.M{{"$project": bson.M{"likes": 1,
        "likeCount": bson.M{"$size": "$likes"}}}})
    result := []bson.M{}
    err = pipe.All(&result)
    if err != nil {
        //handle error
    }
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Comment: Were there any errors? You seem to have the error handling part commented out.

Comment: I ran an example on my local machine with no issue.  What versions are you using for Go and Mongo? I would also recommend building a struct for your results instead of using the bson.M

Comment: I got th error saying "exception: The argument to $size must be an Array, but was of type: EOO"